# as3 calling a function in Main.as Document Class from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, function, class, scope

I am sure this is a popular question but I can't find the exact answer I need. I simply need to access a function or functions created in the Main.as document class. I have tried several methods and they do not seem to work. Here is one example I tried.

**anotherClass.as** // This needs to access functions Main.as

```
package com 
{
import Main;

public class anotherClass
    {
private var stageMain:Main;

public function anotherClass() 
        {
    // tries to call a function in Main.as called languageLoaded. NO WORK!  
        stageMain.languageLoaded("English");
    // in the Main.as languageLoaded is a public function

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this [question and/or its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370222/accessing-the-document-class-in-as3/373591#373591) help?

Comment: I actually read this post. I tried this and it didn't work. But I could not figure out what this line meant. Main.instance.usefulInstanceMethod(); I was wondering why its instance and not _instance.

Comment: _instance is a private property, you cannot access it; while "instance" is a getter function that returns the "_instance" property. So if you call Main.instance = it returns the private _instance of the class.

Comment: I found a work around and posted the code below. Its really a work around for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleaner way is to simply pass a reference to `Main` to the constructor of the class you want to be able to access it.

For example, your `AnotherClass` could look like this:

```
class AnotherClass
{
    private var _main:Main;

    public function AnotherClass(main:Main)
    {
        _main = main;
        _main.test(); // Success!
    }
}
```

And your main class:

```
class Main
{
    public function Main()
    {
        var another:AnotherClass = new AnotherClass(this);
    }

    public function test():void
    {
        trace("Success!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Now I understand it. Thanks for you patience with me Marty! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainDoc extends MovieClip // as long as it extends eventDispatcher you re fine
{
  private var otherClass:OtherClass;
  public function MainDoc()
  {
    otherClass = new OtherClass();
    otherClass.addEventListener("otherClassCustomEvent", onOtherClassReady);
    otherClass.startLogic();
  }
  public function onOtherClassReady(event:Event = null)
  {
    trace("from other class:", otherClass.infoToShare) // traces "from other class: YOLO!"
  }
}

public class OtherClass extends EventDispatcher // must extend the event dispatcher at least
{
  public var infoToShare:String;
  public function OtherClass()
  {
  }
  public function startLogic()
  {
    // do what you got to do
    // when you have your data ready
    infoToShare = "YOLO!";
    dispatchEvent("otherClassCustomEvent");
  }
}
```

Once you're confortable with that, you can start looking into building **custom events** that could carry the variable to send back

Answer (score -1):

Ok I got the following code to work. It's really a messy solution but I didn't know of a better way. It works. I just hope it's stable and does not use a lot of resources.

If you have a much better Idea I am open.

Here is the MainDoc.as

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import com.*;
import com.views.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.system.System;



public class mainDoc extends MovieClip 
    {

    /// (Get Main Doc flow) this creates an instace of the main timeline
    /// and then I send it 
    private static var _instance:mainDoc;
    public static function get instance():mainDoc { return _instance; }



    /// Calls the defaultVars.as in to "vars".
    var vars:defaultVars = new defaultVars();



        public function mainDoc() 
        {
            /// Makes this class ready to be passed to defautVars.as
            _instance = this;
                    // Sends the _instance to defaulVars.as to be accessed later.
            vars.getMainDoc(_instance);

            // Calls a function in defaultVars.as and loads a var
            vars.loadButtonVars("English"); 
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the defaultVars.as

```
package com {
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.*
import flash.net.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;



    public class defaultVars
    {


        /// Makes the MainDoc.as a MovieClip
        // Not sure if this is good but it works. 
        public var MainDoc:MovieClip;


        public function defaultVars() 
        {

        }

        public function getMainDoc(_instance:MovieClip) 
        {
        trace("CALLED" + _instance);
            /// receives the _instance var and its converted to a MovieClip
            // This can now be used in any function because I declared it a public var. 
        MainDoc = _instance;
        }






public function loadButtonVars(Language:String)
    {


    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("Languages/" + Language + "/vars.xml"));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

     function processXML(e:Event):void 
        {
        myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

        /// Home Screen Buttons
        homeT = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeT");
        homeB1 = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeB1");
        homeB2 = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeB2");
        homeB3 = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeB3");
        homeB4 = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeB4");
        homeB5 = myXML.Button.(@Title=="homeB5");


    /// HERE IS WHERE I CALL FUNCTION from MainDoc after xml is loaded. 
    /////////////////
    trace("xml loaded!!!! " + homeB1);
    MainDoc.languageLoaded(Language);



        }

    }



    }

}
```